# AngularJS insert alert box

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am completely new to AngularJS and have been stuck with this. I want to be able to conditionally display a Javascript alertbox on the page.
Suppose I want to do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">
        <script>{{warning}}</script>
    </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.warning = "alert('This is a warning');";
    });
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

So I assumed this has to do with AngularJS sanitizing the string and taking out the javascript. After some googling I tried the following:

```
$scope.warning = $sce.trustAsJS("alert('This is a warning');");
```

I also tried trustAsHtml and added the script tags in the string, but neither displayed the alertbox. Could someone tell me and tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: you should just place the `alert(..)` line in your controller as a normal code

Comment: you don't need to use scope , just place the alert where you want to show it just the way you use in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should actually be like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';

    if ($scope.name==='Superhero') {
        alert("hello");   
    }
}
```

if you want the alert to be shown conditionally by a changing model on view try something like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';

    $scope.$watch('name', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        alert("hello");  
    })
}
```

now every time you will change the 'name' model in your view, the alert will pop-up

refer to the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) for more information about watches

Answer (score 0):

You want $scope.warning to be a function, not the result of the execution of one nor a string.

```
 $scope.warning = function () { alert('This is a warning'); };
```

That way it can be called later in your view : `warning()` should display the alert.

Alternatively, since alert is a function, you may just want to use it as $scope.warning :

```
$scope.warning = alert;
```

+

```
warning('this is a warning')
```

will produce the same result.